# Autoload all classes in a directory using composer, without issuing cammands

Tags: php, composer-php

In my project I have some features that can be extended by end user on production server by just uploading a class file into a specific directory (like Wordpress plugins directory) so this classes can be added and removed dynamically at any time.

Currently I'm doing this using `spl_autoload_register` function.

Can I make this functionality available using Composer, in order to make the project more standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is probably yes, if you stick to PSR-0 or (preferred) PSR-4 standard with your class and file names.